# How to fold a function whose output parameter is two

Tags: function-construction, functional-style

Supposing I have such function:

```
fun[num_] := If[num < 24, num, {24, num - 24}]
```

#### Usage:

```
fun[79]
```

> {24, 55}

I want split the number into some 24 and the remainder.Actually my `fun` is very complicated.But in this case the `{24, 24, 24, 7}` is expected.How to do this?

Comment: Question seems unclear. Seems like `QuotientRemainder` would do most of the work

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks,just a temporary funtion for specify this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a recursion:

```
fun[num_] := If[num < 24, num, {24, Sequence @@ fun[num - 24]}]
```

Comment: It will give `{24, 24, 31}`?

Comment: `fun[num_] := If[num < 24, num, MapAt[fun, {24, num - 24}, 2]];
Flatten@fun[79]`.Will give what I want.Thanks.

Comment: But I don't very like that extra `Flatten`

Comment: @yode Did you `ClearAll[fun]` first?  On my system Coolwater's code returns `{24, 24, 24, 7}` when I evaluate `fun[79]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Wow,It seem I make a mistake,Thanks. :)